# Add a shape to a specific cell in Excel

Tags: excel, shapes

Is it possible to fill a cell within a range (A1:H4) with a rectangle shape so that the entire cell is filled and when the range is sorted the rectangle shape stays with the cell it was placed into?

Original range with 3 shapes added for Washington and Roosevelt

[image]

After sorting on Name column this happens:

[image]

Is it possible to tie a shape to a particular cell?

EDIT: It appears if the shape fits within the size of the cell, then it 'stays' with the cell when the range is sorted?

Answer (score 0):

If you sort across multiple columns using SORT() or using data->sort on the ribbon, it will keep the rows in tact and your colors will stay where they are. For example:

```
=SORT(A2:AH4)
```

will sort those 3 rows in ID# order and keep your colors with each row as it moves.

Comment: Thanks I did that, but the green square stayed with it's original row (Roosevelt) whereas the other two rectangles stayed at their original row number (2).  I created all three rectangles the same - by selecting the shape and eyeballing the size needed, I sorted using the data->sort on the ribbon.

Comment: I may be confused. How are you creating these rectangles? I assumed you were just setting a background color for the cell. If you're drawing a shape over the cell it won't move with the cell. On the Home ribbon menu color those cells with the paint which is next to the text color selection. I can post a screen capture of it above if this isn't clear.

Comment: Thanks - I was creating the shapes in visual basic.  If the shape is even slightly larger than it's containing cell, it won't move with it when sorted - Washington's two shapes remained on row 2.  Roosevelt's shape however, was slightly smaller than the cell so it did stay with the cell when sorted.

Comment: Interesting about the size issue. Why use VB? Will a conditional formatting rule not work? In VB you should not need to create a rectangle. You can likely just color the cell. Is there some reason you need a rectangle to cover the cell? What is the logic for coloring the cells?

Answer (score 0):

[Okay - If the shapes need to sort along with the cells, it is necessary that the shape be completely contained within the cell.](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/drawn-shapes-will-not-sort-with-cells/93c3ddb0-897f-495a-b412-ce401d6a8842)